# Item based collaborative filtering. Since is an unsupervised task should I do training/test split or not?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, train-test-split

I'm learning about recommentation systems and I'm trying to build one using item based collaborative filtering approach. I have this dataset in which the lines correspond the items and columns the user. The matrix is filled with the ratings[1, 5] of the items. I chose sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors class to find the cosine similarities of the items.

If I'm right this dataset doesn't have label. In other words is an unsupervised task(clustering). I would like to know If I have to do the train/test split in this case. I'm asking this beacuse all code videos i've watched on youtube the guys don't do this but in some theory videos they say this step of the pipeline should be done.

Thanks!